# Swift 3.0 Setting Annotation Pin Color for MapView

Tags: swift, annotations, android-mapview, mkannotationview

I am having trouble setting a pin color for my map annotation. I have a function in my MapView viewcontroller that pulls from an array from another view controller and depending on the case of the type, I want different pin colors for the map view. I am not sure how I can add the pin color information to the annotation within this switch statement. My understanding of annotations is rather weak so any explanations, rather than the solution itself, are greatly appreciated.

```
class ColorPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var pinColor: UIColor

    init(pinColor: UIColor) {
        self.pinColor = pinColor
        super.init()
    }
}


    func add(newLocation location_one:[String:Any]) {

    let momentaryLat = (location_one["latitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
    let momentaryLong = (location_one["longitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue

    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    switch location_one["type"] {
        case "Tomorrow":
            print("The pin color is red")
            annotation = ColorPointAnnotation(pinColor: UIColor.red)
        case "Next Week":
            print("The pin color is green")
            annotation = ColorPointAnnotation(pinColor: UIColor.green)
        default:
            print("The pin color is purple")
            annotation = ColorPointAnnotation(pinColor: UIColor.purpleColor)
    }

    annotation.title = location_one["title"] as? String
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: momentaryLat as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: momentaryLong as CLLocationDegrees)


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    self.map.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate

}


  func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    //        if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
    //            return nil
    //        }

    let identifier = "pinAnnotation"
    var annotationView = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView


    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        let colorPointAnnotation = annotation as! ColorPointAnnotation
        annotationView?.pinTintColor = colorPointAnnotation.pinColor

    }
    //      else {
    //            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    //
    //        }
    //        map.showAnnotations(map.annotations, animated: true)
    return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need move your switch statement into the viewForAnnotation delegate method. Here you when you return a pin, you can customize the color and then return it.

Like so :

```
        annotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
```

---

Updated Answer :

You can subclass MKPointAnnotation, and add a property that stores the type of annotation.

When you create an annotation in your add method, set the property to what ever type of pin it is.

Now in the viewForAnnotation method, mapkit will give the annotation of your type. Look at the set property and determine which color pin to return.

Let me know if you want see some code.

Comment: I added some code based on documentation I've read based on adding a MKPointAnnotation subclass (see edit). How can I reference this subclass in my add method?